# unable to load Image in local packages

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a local package for my flutter project, it's basically a UI library which includes a lot of image assets.

I don't want to load the assets in the package from my main project.

I want to load the assets in the package itself.

Here's what I did,

asset location: package_name/lib/assets

pubspec.yaml: packages/package_name/assets/bg.png

dart file: packages/package_name/assets/bg.png

Answer (score 1):

Here are the step by step instructions to add image in Flutter:

Step 1: At the root of your project, create a new folder called **assets**.

Step 2: Inside the root folder, create another folder called **images**. You can give any name to this folder such as pictures, graphics, etc.

Step 3: Add your images inside the **assets/images** folder.

Step 4: Provide the image path in **pubspec.yaml** file as below.

```
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets: <-- SEE HERE
    - assets/images/lion.png
```

Step 5: Display image using the **Image.asset()** widget

Answer (score 1):

u can use tihs idea

```
var files = Directory("${Directory.current.path.toString()}/lib/assets").listSync(); // this to create list of all file in the path 
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
      print(files.toList()[0].path);// to see the alemint that u have and u //can creat list of all item and reach to them like this above 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
         child: files.isNotEmpty ? Image.file(File('${files.toList()              [0].path}'),fit: BoxFit.fill,) : Text(""),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

do not forget add

```
import 'dart:io';
```